# VS.NET MSI Installer Screen Customization

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer

I've added two textbox screens to my MSI installer, and have a custom installer action that hooks back to the application I'm installing to save config settings to the app.config file.

My question is this:
Other than the MSI property screens that allow you to add default text to the MSI custom textboxes, is there a way to have the MSI grab values to put into the text fields from a file or web service, or something? I don't really want these values hard coded into the MSI property screens, and have to recompile and redistribute to change them.

I'd really like to just throw an XML, or CSV file in WITH the installer, and have it read them out of that file, but I haven't seen a way to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eneded up doing was using GetPrivateProfileString from importing "kernel32" dll, and sticking a custom written INI file next to the MSI. The property screens I was trying to fill out were removed, and now I can deploy a custom INI file with settings on a per client basis, without having to recompile, and make tedious changes to the installer settings in the project. Email or contact me if you want me to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

With a custom action written in native code (C), you can do anything you want in an installer, as long as the user executing the MSI has permission to do so (which depends on whether it's the UI phase or the execute phase of the MSI - the latter is run by a system service).